# How to correctly use regex group capture with the grep command?

Tags: bash, grep

I've got this text:

```
Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no.resi 885000130000, Cek status pesanan di https://tiki.id/resi/
```

And I want to grep only the `885000130000` part this is what I have tried:

```
echo "$text" | grep -Eo 'Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no\.resi (.*),'
```

But the result is always

```
Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no.resi 885000130000,
```

I just want grep to show the number only `885000130000`. How do I do it ?

Comment: use PCRE if you have GNU grep.. otherwise, use sed/awk...

Comment: please provide a complete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ awk '{print $7+0}' file
885000130000
```

then edit your question to clarify your requirements. If you need to match the rest of that string then either of these might be what you need instead:

```
$ awk '/Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no\.resi/{print $7+0}' file
885000130000

$ awk 'sub(/Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no\.resi/,""){print $0+0}' file
885000130000
```

It just depends on the unspoken details of your requirements. Any of the above will work efficiently, robustly, and portably with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box and are trivial to modify if/when your requirements change.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about `awk`

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**

```
echo "$text" | grep -oP 'Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no\.resi \K(\d+)'
```

Comment: For readers, the key bit here is `\K` which causes the uses the preceding text to match, but then forgets about it and only reports on the subsequent pattern.

Comment: Pedantically, the parentheses are not needed.

Comment: You should mention that `-P` and `-o` are both GNU grep only and that according to the providers `-P` is "highly experimental" (see [the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)) and it has been known to core dump etc so YMMV with using it. You'd be far better off with a sed or awk solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your string/Input_file is same as shown example then following may also help you here.

```
awk '{sub(/.*no.resi /,"");sub(/,.*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you only print the lines with the option `-n` followed by `.../p`.
This solution only shows one match per line.

```
echo "${text}" | sed -n 's/.*Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no\.resi (.*),.*/\1/p'
```

In your current example you only want ALL the digits:

```
echo "${text}" | grep -Eo "[0-9]*"
```

or (when you have other numbers) use 2 `grep's`:

```
echo "${text}" | 
   grep -Eo 'Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI, no\.resi [0-9]*,' | grep -Eo "[0-9]*"
```

Comment: Thank you, I just want to make sure that I grab the right number just in case there are other numbers present.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[, ]' '{print $8}' file

output
885000130000
```